# Split specific chain of digits from a string

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, regex-greedy

There is this table (called data) below:

```
row    comments
  1    Fortune favors https://something.aaa.org/show_screen.cgi?id=548545 the 23 bold
  2    No man 87485 is id# 548522 an island 65654.       
  3    125 Better id NEWLINE #546654 late than 5875565 never.
  4    555 Better id546654 late than 565 never
```

I used the query below:

```
select row, substring(substring(comments::text, '((id|ID) [0-9]+)'), '[0-9]+') as id 
from data 
where comments::text ~* 'id [0-9]+';
```

This query output ignored rows 1 to 3. It just processed row 4:

```
row   id
 4    546654
```

Does some of you know how to properly split the ID number? Note that the ID contains up to 9 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regexp_replace():

```
SELECT c.rownr
        , regexp_replace (c.comments, e'.*[Ii][Dd][^0-9]*([0-9]+).*', '\1' ) AS the_id
        , c.comments AS comments
FROM comments c
        ;
```

- `.*` matches the initial garbage
- `[Ii][Dd] matches the Id string, case insignificant
- `[^0-9]*` consumes al non-numeric characters
- `([0-9]+)` Matches the numeric string that you want
- `.*`matches any trailing characters
- `'\1'` (in the 3rd argument) tells that you want the stuff matched inside the first `()`

Results:

```
 rownr | the_id |                         comments                                    
-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 | 548545 | Fortune favors https://something.aaa.org/show_screen.cgi?id=548545 the 23 bold
     2 | 548522 | No man 87485 is id# 548522 an island 65654.       
     3 | 546654 | 125 Better id NEWLINE #546654 late than 5875565 never.
     4 | 546654 | 555 Better id546654 late than 565 never
(4 rows)
```